# Dialogflow followup intent creates new context for every new child intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on dialogflow follow up intent.And structure is something like this.

[image]

It create new context for every new intent.

[image]

for example see in repeat intent

[image]

when ever I create any new intent it create new context for it. As you can see in image. When I try to remove any one of those context it remove that intent as followup intent.

So my question is:

This is how dialog flow works or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you're worried about this? Are you trying to do something that this is limiting or causing a problem with? Or are you just curious about why they did this? (Being curious is fine, and we're happy to discuss the reasons - just that if you're having a problem, we want to make sure we answer it and help you do what you need to do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how Dialogflow works. You're not doing anything wrong. (Are the Contexts causing a problem of some sort?)

Followup Intents are just shortcuts for creating separate Intents and giving them an Incoming Context to make sure they can only be triggered after an Intent with the corresponding Outgoing Context. You don't need to use Followup Intents - they're just a convenient way to force that Intent to *only* be triggered after the parent Intent.

If you need an Intent to be triggered either after the initial Intent or at any time - you don't want this as a Followup Intent, just make it a regular Intent. It can still be triggered after the original Intent.

Followup Intents are useful for limited answer handling after a question, but they're not useful for everything, particularly if the user can make free-form comments at any time (which is common during a conversation!). Don't feel you have to be limited and use them.

Answer (score 2):

In Dialogflow, contexts are used to bind intents & direct a user to a certain direction. Output of one intent goes to input of another one so unless & until you call first intent, you won't be able to call second one.

Now coming to your question, with follow-up intents, you can design situations that may follow parent intent. What you're saying is correct, creating follow-up intents will automatically create new contexts. When you try & delete these auto-created contexts, it will remove intent as follow-up intent as well. This is how it has been designed, there's nothing you can do about it.

Although if you'd like to make existing intent as follow-up of another one, you can do this via REST API, you just have to update the “parentId” and “rootParentId” of your existing intents, the change will be reflected on the UI.

Comment: suppose i have already created 3 intent and for that parent has three context. Now i went on to create 4th followup intent. Now again parent intent create one more context. So in total there are 4 context in my new intent and if i try to remove any one of them it remove it as followup intent. Is this the way it design to work

Comment: I'm confused now, You had `1 parent & 3 follow-ups`, now you created one more follow-up so now you have `1 parent & 4 follow-ups`, then how come your newly created follow-up intent has `4 contexts`? Your parent will have `4 o/p contexts` & each of follow-ups will have `1 i/p context`

Comment: my 4th follow-up intent has all 4 context of parent and when i remove any one of them it remove that intent from follow-up. That is what problem i am facing

Comment: Deleting auto-created contexts from either parent/child intents will automatically remove child intent from follow-up. That is what I have answered above.

Comment: it might be annoying, But what i have understood is parent intent keeps on creating new context for each follow-up intent and add all context as input context of follow-up. As it is happening in screenshot which i have shared.

Comment: Yes exactly. Please let us know if you need any help on this.